# InputStream not resetting even after seek 0

Tags: c#

Assuming I have this line to store my HttpPostedFile(s)

```
List<HttpPostedFile> originalUploadedFiles
```

Originally I have this to read the input stream

```
foreach (var file in uploadedFiles)
{
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(file.InputStream);
    formData.Add(streamContent, "files", file.FileName);
}
```

However, if the code runs the second time, my stream content length happens to be 0. Now I know that after reading a stream, it will be in the last position, so I went ahead and attempt to reset the stream using:

```
foreach (var file in uploadedFiles)
{
    if (file.InputStream.CanSeek) file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(file.InputStream);
    formData.Add(streamContent, "files", file.FileName);
}
```

But for some reason, the content-length still happens to be 0.

Comment: So have you debugged through the code? Does `file.InputStream.CanSeek` actually return true? Why are you flushing the input stream?

Comment: Well, the most obvious problem is that `originalUploadedFiles` is not `uploadedFiles`, but I'm assuming that's a typo.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sorry, pasted the flush code by accident. And to answer your question, yes `CanSeek` returns true. However, when watching the `file` object, the length is actually 0.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's a different function

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream?source=recommendations&view=netframework-4.8.1 ? The file content is there  read a little bit different...